# Paste operation in QGraphicsView

Tags: qt

I am implenting copy paste operation in QGraphicsView to different entites like circle, point, ellipse etc. Applied copy operation but unable to get how to apply paste operation for it. Please help me out solve the problem. My slot for copy appears as follows:

cadgraphicsscene.cpp

```
void CadGraphicsScene::copy()
{
   selectItems();

}



void CadGraphicsScene::selectItems()
{
    // refresh record of selected items and their starting positions
    selectedItems.clear();
    foreach (QGraphicsItem *item, itemList)
    {
        if (item->isSelected())
        {
            if (dynamic_cast<QGraphicsItem *>(item))
            {
                selectedItems.append(qMakePair(
                                          dynamic_cast<QGraphicsItem *>(item),
                                          item->scenePos()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

cadgraphicsscene.h

```
#ifndef CADGRAPHICSSCENE_H
#define CADGRAPHICSSCENE_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QXmlStreamWriter>
#include <QUndoStack>

#include "cadcommandadd.h"
#include "cadcommanddelete.h"
#include "cadcommandmove.h"

class CadGraphicsScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CadGraphicsScene(QObject *parent, QUndoStack *);
    enum Mode { NoMode, PointMode, LineMode, CircleMode, EllipseMode, TextMode };

    QFont font() const
    {
        return myFont;
    }

    QColor textColor() const
    {
        return myTextColor;
    }

    void setTextColor(const QColor &color);
    void setFont(const QFont &font);
    void deleteItems();
    void copy();
    void writeStream(QXmlStreamWriter *stream);
    void readStream(QXmlStreamReader *stream);

public slots:
    void setMode(Mode mode);
    void selectItems();
    void editorLostFocus(mText *item);

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent);
    void setFlags();
    void areItemsSelectable(bool);

signals:
    void textInserted(QGraphicsTextItem *item);
    void itemSelected(QGraphicsItem *item);

private:
    Mode entityMode;
    QUndoStack *mUndoStack;

    bool mFirstClick;
    bool mSecondClick;
    bool mThirdClick;
    bool mPaintFlag;
    QVector<QPointF> stuff;
    QPointF start_p, mid_p, end_p, move_p, check_p;
    QPen paintpen, linePen;

    QList<QGraphicsItem *> itemList;
    Point *pointItem;
    Line *lineItem;
    Circle *circleItem;
    Ellipse *ellipseItem;
    mText *textItem;
    QColor myTextColor;
    QFont myFont;

    typedef QPair<QGraphicsItem *, QPointF> itemPos;
    QList<itemPos> selectedItems;
};

#endif // CADGRAPHICSSCENE_H
```

Comment: How means on what actions and how should paste be applied or how paste logic would work ?

Comment: Your question asks about implementing copy/paste in a QGraphicsView, but the code refers to a QGraphicsScene, so which one do you mean? A QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView are not the same thing.

Comment: I want to implement my copy paste funcion on the scene which is present on the view.

Comment: Please help me out to solve the problem.